# PHP array_merge combining arrays with same values

Tags: php, arrays

I have two arrays that I am combining into one and I have several that could possibly be duplicates. I looked at the examples already and it doesn't quite makes sense. Here's an example what I am trying to achieve.

```
array1 ('Make and Model 1', 'Make and Model 2', 'Make and Model 1'...);
array2 ('Serial Number 1', 'Serial Number 2', 'Serial Number 3'...);
array3 ('Other Make and Model 1', 'Other Make and Model 2', 'Other ake and Model 3'...);
array4 ('Other Serial Number 1', 'Other Serial Number 2', 'Other Serial Number 3'...);
$make = array_merge($array1, $array3);
$serial = array_merge($array2, $array4);
foreach (array_combine($make, $serial) as $model => $number): 
     if(($model == "") || $model == "Other"):
...Code...
endif;
endforeach;
```

Now as you can see I have two Make and Model 1's. What is happening, is that it is combining the arrays, but replacing the first Make and Model 1 with the second one which then displays what I'm trying to do with one less item than what my client's customers are getting. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: please refer to the PHP manual. It explains in detail how those functions work, how they are expected to work and any thing you may need to know.

Comment: It looks like you haven't accepted any answers to any of your questions yet. If your problems have been solved, don't forget to accept an answer. If you require any clarification you can leave a comment here. You can include the name of a user (e.g. @Tom) if you would like to notify them of your response.

Comment: sorry @TomFenech. I forgot to respond. Your solution worked!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arrays can contain repeated values but, for obvious reasons, cannot contain repeated keys. `array_combine` will overwrite the value corresponding to each duplicate key it finds.

Assuming that all your serial numbers are unique, a simple solution would be to swap round your `array_combine` to make the serial number the key:

```
foreach (array_combine($serial, $make) as $number => $model):
```

If you have a one-to-many relationship between "make" and "serial number", you might want to consider changing your data structure so that each make corresponds to an array of serial numbers.